# What are the instance that are storage optimised in Google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking to integrate a storage product into the GCP market-place

I would like to know about the following information for having storage optimised instance:

1. What is the theoretical maximum network cap per instance? which instance type provides the max network cap? what are the rule of thumb while selecting instance to get high speed, low latency network fabric and no network oversubscription?
2. is it possible to have multiple interfaces to aggregate the network cap for an instance?
3. will there be any network oversubscription on the GCP network? will network performance scale by adding more instances?
4. as a storage server instance, would need to have better performing internal disks, a minimum of 2 drives, max up to the network limitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this information can be read from the official documentation:
Regarding questions of the first point:

> The egress traffic from a given VM instance is subject to maximum
>   network egress throughput caps. These caps are dependent on the number
>   of cores that the VM instance has. Each core is subject to a 2 Gbps
>   cap for peak performance. Each additional core increases the network
>   cap, up to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbps for each instance. The
>   actual performance you experience will vary depending on your
>   workload. All caps are meant as maximum possible performance, and not
>   sustained performance. [1](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/data-centers/networking)
>
> One feature of GCP that can help you get the most out of your
>   investment is the ability to specify Custom VM types. When choosing
>   the size of your filer, you can pick exactly the right mix of memory
>   and CPU, so that your filer is operating at optimal performance
>   without being oversubscribed.[2](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine)

About the second point:

> Maximum number of network interfaces The maximum number of virtual
>   interfaces allowed per instance is 8. The number of interfaces allowed
>   in an instance is dependent on the instance's machine type and the
>   number of vCPUs. In general, the following rules apply for
>   n1-standard-x, n1-highmem-x, n1-highcpu-x, f1-micro, g1-small and
>   custom VMs:
>
> 2 network interfaces for VM <= 2vCPU 1 network interface per vCPU for
>   VM > 2vCPUs, with a cap of max 8 network interfaces per VM
>   [3](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#max-interfaces)

Regarding the third point, there wont be any bandwidth change since there is no network over subscription. The network performance won't scale but you will clearly gain high availability by using different zones and balancing. But to better address this you will need to provide more context on what you really want to achieve.